Radiation from a stationary charge relative to earth for a free falling observer
It is my understanding that if we have a charge at rest on earth, a free falling observer will see it radiating, as the charge is in an accelerated frame of reference. This observer can in principle collect this radiation and so he will be slowed down by the radiation pressure.
How an observer at rest on earth will explain this deceleration, what force is responsible for it in his frame of reference, where the charge is not radiating? (I have heard that rindler horizons prevent the observer at earth from seeing the radiation, but this is not convincing to me because the free falling observer is in principle outside of the rindler horizon, as he is perfectly visible from the earth's surface).

The standard definition for acceleration in CM Or GR is the vector $a^{\mu}=u^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}u^{\mu}$, while free falling refers to the special case where $a^{\mu}=0$. I didn't understand how a free falling observer will see a charge to be accelerating. Maybe you can clarify what you mean by accelerating frame of reference

I am not sure what are you asking, it is common knowledge that a charge at rest on teh surface on earth is in a non inertial accelerated frame, also measured by an accelerometer. A free falling observer will be the one accelerating in the newtonian picture, but it is in an inertial frame in GR.
